# Google Books API - using langrestrict=en still returns non english results

Tags: google-books, google-books-api

This request: https://books.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=intitle%3Apercy&langRestrict=en
Still returns non English books, as a first results, might I add! Seems any other language works though. Help!

Sending the request I was expecting to get only books in English, but I also get books in other languages.